# UITextField is not key value coding-compliant for the key provider in iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c

The common solution for the memory leak problem for UITextField above iOS 11.2 is as follows:

```
- (void) didMoveToWindow {
  [super didMoveToWindow];
  if (@available(iOS 11.2, *) {
    NSString *keyPath = @"textContentView.provider";
    @try {
      if (self.window){
        id provider = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
        if (!provider && self) {
          [self setValue:self forKeyPath:keyPath];
        } else {
          [self setValue:nil forKeyPath:keyPath];
        }
      }
    } @catch (NSException *e) {
      NSLog("%@",e);
    }
}
```

However, in iOS 13, such solution will cause a white screen problem, and the error log in console is

```
[<_UITextFieldCanvasView 0x7f8338476700> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key provider.
```

Is there any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: iOS/iPadOS 13 is still beta so this might get fixed (crossing fingers), but as always you can also check for respond to selector for valueForKeyPath: and setValue:nil before calling them.

Comment: About what memory leak you're talking, exactly?
This code looks smelly for me. You doing something you should not do.

I wanna suggest you to get rid of it, but can't do that until I know what exactly it is needed for.